# Manually binding complex model array to controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

For some reason I'm trying to manually bind an array of a Complex Model but I'm getting a null reference exception in my controller, the binder doesn't retrieve the parameter. I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329721/mvc-net-binding-complex-models) which is very similar (the only difference is actually the type of the model) but I don't understand why it doesn't work in my case.

Here is what I have.

In my controller

```
public ActionResult MyAction(ComplexType[] models)
{
    foreach(ComplexType c in models) // Exception at this point, the parameter is null
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

In my View :

```
    @using(Html.BeginForm("MyAction","Controller"))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<table>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model._MyProperty.Count; i++ )
        {
            var d = Model._MyProperty[i];
            @:<tr>
                @:<td> @Html.CheckBox("models.Property1["+i+"]", d.Property1) 
                    @Html.Hidden("models.ID["+i+"]",d.ID)
                    @Html.Hidden("models.Property2["+i+"]")
                    @Html.Hidden("models.Property3["+i+"]")
                    @Html.Hidden("models.Property4["+i+"]")
                @:  </td>
            @:</tr>
        }

 //Submit Button
 </table>

}
```

And here is my class :

```
class ComplexType
{
    int ID {get;set;}
    int Property1{get;set;}
    int Property2{get;set;}
    int Property3{get;set;}
    int Property4{get;set;}
}
```

I've tried to change ComplexType[] to ICollection in the controller but it didn't work. Also, just for info, my ViewModel is not the Model i'm tying to bing. I need to have several forms working on different datatypes in this single view.

Answer (score 2):

You are naming your elements in the loop as follows

```
<input type="hidden" name="models.Property2[0]" value
<input type="hidden" name="models.Property2[1]" value
```

when it should be

```
<input type="hidden" name="models[0].Property2" value
<input type="hidden" name="models[1].Property2" value
```