# How to pass an object having a list type property in a ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, cart

I know [This type of question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222533/polymorphic-model-binding) is asked before but i don't understand how to solve the problem with the answers that is already provided. don't even understand where to write those ModelBinder code. so i will just describe my problem.
I have a view which is strongly typed to a model that has a list property(association relationship).

```
public class Sales
{
    public int SalesSl { get; set; }
    public double TotSalAmt { get; set; }
    public double TotCashRec { get; set; }
    public double TotVat { get; set; }
    public double TotDiscnt { get; set; }
    public int CustomerSupplyId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public double SalesRt { get; set; }
    public double SalesQty { get; set; }
    public double PurchaseRt { get; set; }
    public double ProductDisAmt { get; set; }
    public double ProductVat { get; set; }
    public double LaborCost { get; set; }
    public string SalesNote { get; set; }
    public int SalesIndex { get; set; }
    public List<AddedProductView> AddedProductViews { get; set; }

    public Sales()
    {
        AddedProductViews = new List<AddedProductView>();
    }
}
  [Serializable]
public class AddedProductView
{       
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Unit { get; set; }
    public string UnitDescription { get; set; }
    public double Rate { get; set; }
    public double Vat { get; set; }
    public double Discount { get; set; }
    public double NetAmount { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }
    public int SalesIndex { get; set; }
}
```

Now, i have no problem when i pass the sales model to the view. it shows all of the product that is already contained in the AddedProductViews.
The view:

```
<form id="SalesModForm">
    <div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-0 panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Purchase Product
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-success">
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IndexSl)
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SalesSl, null, new { style = "width:120px" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustSupplyId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustSupplyId, null, new { style = "width:120px" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductId) <p class="indent"></p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductId, null, new { style = "width:120px" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Qty")
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SalesQty, null, new { style = "width:60px" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Rate")
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SalesRt, null, new { style = "width:60px" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Add" id="btnAddToCartMod" style="width:100px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <hr />
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Unit</th>
                        <th>Rate</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Vat</th>
                        <th>Discount</th>
                        <th>Net Amount</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (AddedProductView sIAM in Model.AddedProductViews)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @sIAM.ProductName
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @sIAM.Quantity
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @sIAM.Unit
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @sIAM.Rate
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @sIAM.Total
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @sIAM.Vat
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @sIAM.Discount
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @sIAM.NetAmount
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "UpdateProductInfo", new { salesSl = @Model.SalesSl, productId = @sIAM.ProductId, salesDt = @Model.SalesDt })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

```
<div>
  <input type="submit" value="Sale" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSalesMod" />
</div>
```

When I click on the **Remove AcionLink** the model data(sales.AddedProductViews) is changed. Now When I click on **btnSalesMod** i expect the modified Sales data will be saved with help of the following script.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnAddToCartMod').click(function () {
            var data = $('#SalesModForm').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Post',
                url: '/Sales/Index',
                data: data,
                success: function () {
                    window.location = '/Sales/Index';
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

But while i  debug all of the sales data is received to the controller's **ActionResult** parameter except the count of sales.AddedProductViews count is 0, means the parameter is not receiving any value for AddedProductViews property.
In controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Sales sales)
    {
        //no data in sales.AddedProductViews
        //sales.AddedProductViews count = 0;
        return View();
    }
```

So, now my question is how can I get the data that is in AddedProductViews has in the view.

Or is there any other way to pass the AddedProductViews data to the controller??
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try using JSON for the same!

Comment: Tried json.stringfy(), same result @UllasHunka

Comment: can you show me the log for $('#SalesModForm').html

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand what you are asking for. the whole relevant html is in the question

Comment: Well, the list is empty because you don't have any `<input>` for the items of `Model.AddedProductViews`

Comment: I just wanted to check the data which you are before sending. what is the log of data

Comment: Please look at my Sales Class. every property contains valid data and the AddedProductViews has as many rows as i added to the cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take a look at how model binding works in MVC. When you use any HTML Helper, the name of that control is set to used model property. For example

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SalesSl, null, new { style = "width:120px" })
```

will render an input element with `type="text"` and `name="SalesSl"` and when you will post the form back to server, the value of the control with `name="SalesSl"` will get bound to your Model's property named `SalesSl`.

But when you use something like the following:

```
<td>@sIAM.ProductName</td>
```

there is no control created with the name set to Model Property name.

You need to use for loop instead of foreach loop, and in the loop you need to do something like this for each of your AddedProductView properties that you want to submit back to server:

```
<td>
    @Html.Hidden("AddedProductViews[@index].ProductName", @Model.AddedProductViews[index].ProductName);
    @Model.AddedProductViews[index].ProductName
</td>
```

These links should be helpful:

- [Manually binding complex model array to controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250135/manually-binding-complex-model-array-to-controller-action)
- [Model Binding To A List](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)
- [MVC .NET Model Binding to Array on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496593/mvc-net-model-binding-to-array-on-the-fly)

Comment: Thank you so much!.with the help of the links along with your answer i finally did it.

Comment: Happy to help :)